# AJAX form data is not going through

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My data "category" is not coming through my AJAX request.

I followed a tutorial from 2017, my guess is maybe my syntax is outdated or something similar.

Here is a snippet of my AJAX. 
I have some categories outputted the user can click on.

```
 echo '<div class ="cats" id="categories">';
 echo '<button class="catbutton" name="all" value="all">All 
 categories</button><br>';

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultcats)) {
$jada = $row['category'];
echo ' <button id="category" class="catbutton" name="cat-submitted" 
value="'.$row['category'].'">'.$row['category'].'</button><br>';

echo '</br>';

 }
echo '</div>';

?>
<div id="display">

</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#categories .catbutton').each(function() {
      $(this).click(function(){
var category = $("#catbutton").val();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "demo.php",
  data: category,
  cache: false,
  success: function(result){
$("#display").html(result);
}
});

return false;

});
});
});
```

I then want to use AJAX for when the user clicks on one of the categories. 
I want to get the value of the clicked category, so I later can used it for a SQL query. For now I'm just trying to see if I can get the variable with this code on my "demo.php":

```
<?php
$category = $_POST['category'];
echo $category;

echo "form submitted";
echo $category;

 ?>
```

The AJAX is working partly because:

When the user clicks on a category "form submitted" is popping up as it should, however you don't see any category variable being shown which is what is my main goal.

Comment: Change `data: category` to `data: { "category": category }` in your ajax options.

Comment: You are attempting to get the value of a button with `id` `catbutton` but you don't actually have any such button. perhaps you mean `var category = $(this).val();`?

Comment: @Nick you are correct. I was looking through other SO posts, to fix another problem which was solved by not using IDs, I then did not correct that line. Thank you.

Comment: @Chao1920 no worries, glad that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Before posting here I had an earlier problem with the user click only reacting to my first category.

I solved this by looking at another SO posts which suggested to not using ID's for each button. However I then forgot to change var category = $("#catbutton").val();
to var category = $(this).val();

Changing the above and making the change: data: category to data: { "category": category }

Solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax code seems incorrect. You should change passing parameter code as below:

```
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "demo.php",
      data: {"category": category}
      cache: false,
      success: function(result){
          $("#display").html(result);
      }
  });
```

Here you need to pass data as above. Hope it helps you.